# NSRegularExpression: How to match word starting with @

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'd like to convert references to usernames such as @me, @you, @them (twitter style) to links.  What would be the correct NSRegularExpression pattern for this?

---

Based on the input from answers below, here's what I ended up using...

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?<!\\w)@([\\w\\._-]+)?" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSString *newString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:stringIn options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringIn length]) withTemplate:@"<a href='http://mydomain.com/$1'>$0</a>"];
```

This may not be a perfect match for Twitter, as my own site supports dots, dashes and underlines

Comment: Works good.  As E-madd points out in his edit, if you're using this for Twitter, you want to disallow periods and hyphens, so the pattern is "(?<!\\w)@([\\w\\_]+)?".  Underscores are allowed in twitter usernames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` should get the job done pretty well.

I would recommend throwing some test data in [RegExr](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/) and fiddling with the regex to match exactly what you need to.

Comment: Ampersand does not have to be escaped. Twitter names might also contain underlines.

Comment: Also, the asterisk means zero or more occurences, so this will match an `@` by itself.

Comment: @dreamlax Good catch. My bad. @Nikolai I am hoping that anyone that wishes to use regexes at least understands them enough to make minor modifications to them. Anyways, answer is updated to reflect both criticisms.

Answer (score 3):

`(?<!\w)@\w+` should be pretty safe.

The `(?<!\w)` is called a [Negative Lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and makes sure there's no word character before the @, preventing to match email addresses.